# Searching a Sharepoint list from a Powerapp is working for one column but not another

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a Sharepoint list "Equipment Log 3" which has these fields:

- Item (renamed from the default "Title" field)
- First name
- Last Name
- Start Date
- End Date

I tied this list to a Gallery in a canvas app screen. I have a TextSearch textbox that i am using as input for Search functionality.
When I set Gallery-> Items to

```
Search('Equipment Log 3', TextSearch.Text, "Title")
```

everything works fine. See images below

[search by text - blank value][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yec7U.png

[search by text - value][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t84Tl.png

But when I set it to

```
Search('Equipment Log 3', TextSearch.Text, "First Name")
```

or

```
Search('Equipment Log 3', TextSearch.Text, "First_x0020_Name")
```

(as recommended in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup)

it gives an error stating

```
"The specified column First Name does not exist"
```

[error first name ][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2uA9.png

But that column exists since the Gallery's subtitle label is set to display Fist name & Last Name.

[full name][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkf6Z.png

Why is the search working for one column but not the other?

Also, when I search by "Item", renamed from "Title", it does not work, but it works for "Title" the default field name given by Sharepoint when I created the list. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names from sharepoint with spaces should have the spaces removed, so "FirstName" would work for you. That piece of documentation is out of date and I'm having it updated.

Comment: Searching by "FirstName" worked. Thank you for your reply and having the documentation updated.